# Fixed Height for Vertical Scrollbar to Appear? No JS, only CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set a fixed height for when the vertical scrollbar begins to be visible on the browser.  My container is only 500px high. I set the body to 500px high.  But I also have a footer that is about 30px high below the container. So my entire page is about 530px. However I don't want the page to start scrolling when it detects the bottom of the footer, but rather at the bottom of the container. Is there any way to ignore my footer so the page doesn't begin to scroll until 500px??

My markup:

```
<body>
<div id="veritcal"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
    <div id="row1">
        <div id="box1">content</div>
        <div id="box1">content</div>
        <div id="box1">content</div>
        <div id="box1">content</div>
        <div id="box1">content</div>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Some Footer Content</div>

</body>
```

My css:

```
html,body{
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body{
font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
font-size: 1em;
font-style: normal;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
min-width: 800px;
min-height: 500px;
}

#vertical{
position: relative;
height: 50%;
margin-top: -250px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
width: 100%;
}

#container{
position: relative;
width: 800px;
height: 500px;
padding: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
z-index: 0;
}

#footer{
margin-left:auto;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
width: 550px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #000000;
color: rgba(0, 166, 172, 0.3);
line-height: 2.0em;
font-size: 0.7em;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
opacity: 0;
}

#footer:hover{
opacity: 1;
}
```

So again, my page begins scrolling at 530px at the bottom of the footer. I have the container horizontally centered and my #vertical div makes the container center vertically.  When I resize the browser, the top of the container stops at the top of the browser perfectly, but then the browser vertical scrollbar appears at 530px instead of 500px, which I set for the min-height of the body.  Not sure why it still appears at 530px.

Comment: As mentioned below with Mujtaba's answer, I can't use display: none; because then I won't be able to use rollover effects with my footer. Is there any other solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I propably understood what you want, i think that you need to use in #footer in css

```
display: none;
```

instead of

```
opacity: 0;
```

I hope that will help you ...

---

if you want to use **#footer:hover** , may this code help you
in **#footer** , try this

```
#footer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    width: 550px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: rgba(0, 166, 172, 0.3);
    line-height: 2.0em;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    /*add this code*/
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -285px;
}
```

you can also use

```
position: absolute;
```

instead of

```
position: fixed;
```

maybe this will solve your problem ...

Comment: This does take care of the scroll problem. But I have my footer set up to appear when you hover over it.  This makes it so the hover effect doesn't work anymore, even if I put #footer:hover{display:block}. It's not a link, so I don't want to wrap it in a href tag.  How do I keep my rollover? I edited my question above to show my rollover in the css.

Comment: So in order for my footer to appear as a rollover with display:none; I have to put a <div> inside my footer div, which then ruins the whole point of using display:none; because then I have to put it on the #footer:hover div{} I have gone back through and tried using css animations, or something else to get the rollover to work, but then the scrollbar issue comes back. So the answer above does not work for me. Sorry.

Comment: Used your second part and it does work! position: absolute; does not, but the position: fixed; does. I did not use the display: none; at the top.  Thank you very much for your help!